# Discord JS delete webhook on channels

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i learn a little with the java script and discord.js and i have a little problem

I'am making a fun command if i mention someone and the message it's create a webhook with his username + avatar and send the message i want

The code work but after 10 webhooks created i can't continue use the commands, is it possible to delete the webhook after using it or just delete all webhook on the channel ?

I'm using node and i have install hookcord for send message with webhooks

my code:

```
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "say")) //say something like if it's a member    
            {    
              message.delete()   
              args[0] = message.mentions.members.first()  
              var usermentions = args[0]    
              let msg = args[1];
              message.channel.createWebhook(usermentions.displayName, usermentions.user.displayAvatarURL).then(wb =>            
              {       
                var hookcord = require('hookcord');
                var Hook = new hookcord.Hook()
                  .setLink(`https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/${wb.id}/${wb.token}`)
                  .setPayload({
                    'title': usermentions.displayName,
                    'avatar': usermentions.user.displayAvatarURL,
                    'content': msg
                  })
                  .fire()
                  .then(function(response) {})
                  .catch(function(e) {})
              })
            }
```

Thanks in advance for your times and your help !

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `channel.fetchWebhooks()` and then use a forEach loop to delete all of them:

```js
if(message.content === 'delete-webbooks'){
   message.channel.fetchWebhooks().then((webhooks) => {
       webhooks.forEach((wh) => wh.delete());
   });
}
```

You can also replace:

```js
.then(function(response) {})
```

by:

```js
.then(function(response) {
    wb.delete();
})
```

I think it's the best solution.

Comment: Thanks you, it's working !! but i have again one question when i make my code like: /say @user Hello i'm a bot, only the message Hello show and not i'm a bot did you know why ?

Comment: Replace `let msg = args[1];` by `let msg = args.slice(1).join(" ");`